# Array with Z code in java

Tags: java, arrays

I try to make a program in java with present one
alphabet in form of "Z". But the array is my weakness. 
Someone can help me please?

Example:

[image: I need to print this]

```
package Learning;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Z {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Rows ");
        int matrixRow = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Columns: ");
        int matrixCol = scan.nextInt();



        if (matrixRow > 50 && matrixCol > 50) {
            System.out.print("ERROR");
        }
        if (matrixRow != matrixCol) {
            System.out.print("ERROR");
        if (matrixRow <= 2 && matrixCol <= 2) {
            System.out.print(" ERROR");
        }


        int[][] matrix = new int[matrixRow][matrixCol];

        for (int i = 65; i < matrixRow; i++) {
            for (int j = matrixRow; j < matrixCol; j++) {

            }

            for (int l = 0; l < matrixRow; l++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < matrixCol; c++) {
                    System.out.print(array[matrixRow][matrixCol] + "\t");
                }

                System.out.println();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to give more details what exactly you are struggling with. "The array is my weakness" certainly doesn't tell me much.

Answer (score 2):

It never enters the first loop, because matrixRow is maximum 50, and if i is 65, that's not smaller, than max 50.
You also forgot to close the body of the 2nd if.
'array' in the innermost loop should be 'matrix'

And a complete solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter The Size Of The Matrix (3-50)");
    int matrixSize = scan.nextInt();

    if (matrixSize < 3 || matrixSize > 50) {
        System.out.print("Wrong Size");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        System.out.print((char)(i % 26 + 65));
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize - 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < matrixSize; j++) {
            if (i + j == matrixSize - 1) {
                System.out.print((char) ((i + matrixSize) % 26 + 65));
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        System.out.print((char)((i + (2 * matrixSize) - 2) % 26 + 65));
    }
}
```

Comment: please mark as solution if it works as you needed it